# CentOS - change the password of GPG file by bash script

Tags: bash, centos, gpg

I am looking for a bash script which input is the old and the new password for changing password of a *.gpg file.

I encrypted a txt file with command `gpg -c`. System create a `file.txt.gpg`. How can I change the passphrase that I created before?

Comment: You *encrypt* a file if you do `gpg -c`, I assumed that was a typo and corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the passphrase, but you can decrypt and reencrypt:

```
gpg --decrypt file.txt.gpg | (gpg -c > tmp.gpg && mv tmp.gpg file.txt.gpg)
```

You shouldn't directly redirect to your encrypted file (it still needs to be decrypted) and the `&&` make sure the `mv` is not executed unless the encryption succeeded.

The above will prompt you once for your decryption password and then twice for the encryption.

Comment: thanks, that help a lot. I wonder if you correct this code for me `{basename \home\hieu\test.txt.gpg}::-4` I want to delete 4 character of the string which is test.txt.gpg Thanks alredy!

Comment: @H.Dinh If you are using Bash, try `x="\home\hieu\test.txt.gpg"` and then `echo ${x%.gpg}`. That is much better than mucking with `basename` (which you would have to put in between `$(   )`)